# Google Custom Search API for spelling check

Tags: android, spell-checking, google-custom-search

I want to use Google Custom Search API in order to obtain the spelling suggestion for a word or a phrase in my android application. I found this function https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#results_xml_tag_Spelling but I don't understand how I can use it..

Answer (score 0):

Make a call for the advanced search, then see if there is value in Spelling-Suggestion:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#XML_Results_for_Regular_and_Advanced_Search_Queries
as in example above, q=socer and the suggestion is soccer